# Display Hex and Color of Web color based on Name

Tags: processing

This code is written using the latest version of Processing. This has been compiled and proven working.

What this code does: Enter name of the web color listed in Wikipedia in the text field. Or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> for a random color.

How to compile: Get the latest version of Processing (3.3) and copy-paste the code. Press run, and it should work.

```
//array containing web color hex 
color[] hex = {#FFFFFF, #C0C0C0, #808080, #000000,
               #FF0000, #800000, #FFFF00, #808000,
               #00FF00, #008000, #00FFFF, #008080,
               #0000FF, #000080, #FF00FF, #800080};

//array containing hex values as string for further display
String[] value = {"#FFFFFF", "#C0C0C0", "#808080", "#000000",
               "#FF0000", "#800000", "#FFFF00", "#808000",
               "#00FF00", "#008000", "#00FFFF", "#008080",
               "#0000FF", "#000080", "#FF00FF", "#800080"};

//array containing web colors' names
String[] name = {"white", "silver", "gray", "black", "red",
                 "maroon", "yello", "olive", "lime", "green",
                 "aqua", "teal", "navy", "fuchsia", "purple"};

PFont colorFont; //font for color names
PFont numberFont; //font for hex numbers

String defaultText = ""; //default text displayed when the app starts, will be rand
String defaultValue = ""; //default hex value displayed, rand
String instructions = "Write the name of your desired Web Color \n and presss Enter \n or CTRL for a random color"; //instructions
color defaultColor = #FFFFFF; //default color at the start, will be rand
color bgColor;
String colorName;
String colorValue;

//method for randomizing startup color
void initiate()
{
  int index = int(random(name.length));
  defaultText = name[index];
  defaultColor = hex[index];
  defaultValue = value[index];

  bgColor = defaultColor;
  colorName = defaultText;
  colorValue = defaultValue;


}


void setup()
{
  initiate();
  size(640, 480);
  stroke(0);
  colorFont = createFont("strenuous bl.ttf", 32);
  numberFont = createFont("NotCourierSans.otf", 28);
  textAlign(CENTER);

}

void cursor()
{
  float cursorPos = textWidth(colorName); //cursor position
  stroke(255, (125 - map(millis()%3000, 0, 3000, 0, 300))); //blink
  line(cursorPos + (width/2), 150, cursorPos + (width/2), 234); //placing the cursor
}


//a new surface for the background circle
void bgCircle()
{
  color bgcolor = #FFE11B;
  PGraphics bgc = createGraphics(1000, 1000);
  bgc.beginDraw();
  bgc.fill(bgcolor, 160);
  bgc.ellipse(width/2, height/2, 435, 435);
  bgc.endDraw();
  image(bgc, 0, 0);
}


void draw()
{
  background(bgColor); 
  textSize(14);
  bgCircle();
  text(instructions, width/2, 120);
  textFont(colorFont);
  text(colorName.toLowerCase(), width/2, 200);
  textFont(numberFont);
  text(colorValue, width/2, 400);
  cursor();



}


//op for randomizign color
void keyReleased()
{
  if (key == CODED)
  {
    if (keyCode == CONTROL)
    {
      initiate();
    }
  }
}


//type and rest
void keyPressed()
{
  if (key == BACKSPACE && colorName.length() > 0)
  {
    colorName = colorName.substring(0, (colorName.length() - 1));
  }

  else if (textWidth(colorName) < width / 6 && colorName.length() < 8 && key != CODED && key != BACKSPACE && key != RETURN && key != ENTER)
  {
    colorName += key;
  }

  else if (key == ENTER || key == RETURN)
  {
    String colorNameLower = colorName.toLowerCase();
    switch (colorNameLower)
    {
      case "white":
        bgColor = hex[0];
        colorValue = value[0];
        break;
      case "silver":
        bgColor = hex[1];
        colorValue = value[1];
        break;
      case "gray":
        bgColor = hex[2];
        colorValue = value[2];
        break;
      case "black":
        bgColor = hex[3];
        colorValue = value[3];
        break;
      case "red":
        bgColor = hex[4];
        colorValue = value[4];
        break;
      case "maroon":
        bgColor = hex[5];
        colorValue = value[5];
        break;
      case "yellow":
        bgColor = hex[6];
        colorValue = value[6];
        break;
      case "olive":
        bgColor = hex[7];
        colorValue = value[7];
        break;
      case "lime":
        bgColor = hex[8];
        colorValue = value[8];
        break;
      case "green":
        bgColor = hex[9];
        colorValue = value[9];
        break;
      case "aqua":
        bgColor = hex[10];
        colorValue = value[10];
        break;
      case "teal":
        bgColor = hex[11];
        colorValue = value[11];
        break;
      case "blue":
        bgColor = hex[12];
        colorValue = value[12];
        break;
      case "navy":
        bgColor = hex[13];
        colorValue = value[13];
        break;
      case "fuchsia":
        bgColor = hex[14];
        colorValue = value[14];
        break;
      case "purple":
        bgColor = hex[15];
        colorValue = value[15];
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @Toto we assume everyone that comes to Code Review wants their code reviewed, so they don't need to ask for it in the question. And so assume they want any and all possible improvements.

Comment: @Peilonrayz It's called Processing, a Java-based graphical language.